# Quadratic algorithm to access a cube

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I have to develop game-of-life in 3D. I started by implementing a 3 dimensional structure.

Example

```
matrix      = ( char *** ) malloc( sizeof( char ** ) * size_cube );
matrix_b    = ( char *** ) malloc( sizeof( char ** ) * size_cube );
for ( i = 0 ; i < size_cube ; i++ ) {
    matrix[ i ]     = ( char ** ) malloc( sizeof( char * ) * size_cube );
    matrix_b[ i ]   = ( char ** ) malloc( sizeof( char * ) * size_cube );
    for ( j = 0 ; j < size_cube ; j++ ) {
        matrix[ i ][ j ]    = ( char * ) malloc( sizeof( char ) );
        matrix_b[ i ][ j ]  = ( char * ) malloc( sizeof( char ) );
    }
}
```

Only the proposed one is:

> The number of individuals will be in the order of O(size<sup>2</sup>),
>   hence the cube will be very sparse. Your implementation should be
>   designed to allocate an amount of space proportional to this value. If
>   a dense data structure to the matrix is used (in the order of
>   O(size<sup>3</sup>)), your program will not be able to handle the
>   largest problem instances.

How can I access a 3D array with a quadratic algorithm?
Any idea?

Comment: Who said it has to be accessed with a quadratic algorithm? It is only stating the number of individuals will be quadratic. But if you really want to, you better change your data structure to contain the list of the individuals (and their coordinates) rather than the grid.

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand that description. I thought that any access to the matrix has to be done with a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Well, yeah. It is telling that your data structure should be quadratic. So your 3D matrix is a miss-shot. Make a linear structure containing the population instead.

Comment: access to the data structure that you've allocated is by 3 int values ie `matrix[2][[2][2]`

Comment: That is not a 3D array. A pointer is not an array. If you want a 3D array, use one! But your assignment explicitly wanrs you both ways are doomed. Oh, and don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: Search for "_sparse matrix data structure in c_" with Google and implement one of those methods.

Comment: Only allocate `matrix[ i ][ j ]` if an element `matrix[ i ][ j ][k]` is not empty.  Only allocate `matrix[ i ]` if an element `matrix[ i ][ j ]` is not empty.

Comment: One possible implementation is a binary tree, using the coordinates as a key. A node needs to hold a flag to indicate whether the cell is occupied and a counter for number of occupied neighbors. Initially, the tree will contain only occupied cells, with counters initialized to 0. For each generation, make two in-order passes over the tree. The first pass checks if a cell is occupied and increments the counters of its neighbors, creating them if necessary. The second pass decides the new state of a cell, clears the counter and possibly deletes it. Traversal needs to cope with edits to the tree.

Comment: @PaulHankin Honestly, I do not understand the logic of the linked lists. I build only with the coordinates of living cells? And the hash points to the neighbors? I did not get the idea ... I do not understand the basic idea of using a linked list.

Comment: I have a problem with similar to the other question but I can not understand the hash logic that holds the coordinates doing so a constant search O (1). Can you explain how to make a hash with the (x, y, z) coordinates to do a constant search?